# It's possible to have multiple instances of jpos Q2?

Tags: java, jboss7.x, jpos

My application is distributed between two EARs: EAR 1 and EAR 2. In EAR1 is the instantiation of class Q2:

Q2 q2 = new Q2 ("dir_xml_1").

In EAR2 is the second instantiation of class Q2, but pointing to another deploy directory:

Q2 q2 = new Q2 ("dir_xml_2").

Both EARs are installed on the same Jboss. However, when I start JBoss, the following error occurs:

javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: Q2:type=system,service=loader

I tried to rename JMX_NAME to allow a new MBean instance by using the -name parameter:

Q2 q2 = new Q2 (new String [] {"- d", "dir_xml_1", "-n", "nameBean1"})

but it did not work. The same error occurred.

I expect each EAR has its own instance of Q2 to read its deploy specific directory, but an error occurs...